# Why was "Note that this Reddit sub is way more informative than this Stack Exchange site." removed from my answer about USCIS?

Tags: discussion, moderation

I wrote

> Note that this Reddit sub [https://www.reddit.com/r/USCIS/] is way more informative than this Stack Exchange site.

in https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/a/26369/164 and https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/a/26368/164. Why did a mod remove it?

I wrote that sentence because I had used information from https://www.reddit.com/r/USCIS/ in my answer, and for USCIS questions,
https://www.reddit.com/r/USCIS/ is way more informative than this Stack Exchange site. I feel it's important to let people interested in USCIS know that https://www.reddit.com/r/USCIS/ is a great place to find information on USCIS.

Answer (score 1):

> < insert site > is way more informative than this Stack Exchange site.

But our charter is not to compete with all of the other sites on the internet to be the best. We're here to be a Q/A site for people looking for help and to be a repository for the information that results from that help. This makes your relative statement fluff, and even possibly counter productive.

I mean when it comes to the UK, immigrationboards.com is the top site in the world for this kind of information, hands down not-even-close (though our equivalent Travel.se is pretty good too). But that's a free flowing open forum format. It's not uncommon for wrong answers to pop up and lead people astray. It has no voting system, and a limited time for editing (10 minutes IIRC). Plus attacks on certain nationalities, sometimes thinly veiled, sometimes not veiled at all, are rife. They've cracked down on that more lately, but it's driven people away.

Reddit atleast has a voting system, and a more open editing system. But I've seen well received contradictory posts on there on several occasions. You often have to dig through their interface, which isn't exactly the most intuitive, and long long threads with branching threads, to finally get to something concrete and confirmed. They have a great thing going there, and I especially like them for their discussions on entertainment related topics. But me going to their immigration related Reddit subs and commenting that Expats is better for < insert reason > is likewise useless fluff - which I would hope their mods would similarly just edit away eventually.

None of our sites are perfect. Some sites are going to be better for some people than this one for some things, or even for just the way some people like to get their information. For others, this site is great.

Until we're told by StackExchange that it's a competition, and dissing and slamming opposing sites is encouraged, you might have to accept that the culture here (and probably at Reddit as well from what I've seen) is to just edit out that kind of thing out.

Comment: Thanks but I'm confused. Was "Note that this Reddit sub [https://www.reddit.com/r/USCIS/] is way more informative than this Stack Exchange site" removed because "it's the culture here", or because you don't like reddit, or because you think that sub would remove mentions of this Stack Exchange site?

Comment: I think mainly because it's just fluff and even potentially counter productive (makes it look a competition - when it's not). Each site has its own plusses and minuses, and some people respond to certain formats more than to others. So your comment was deleted.

Comment: Why do you say it's fluff? It's very valuable information for people immigrating to the US.

Comment: Reddit might indeed be 'more informative' for people wanting to immigrate to the United States. *But this is not a competition.* Some people wanting that kind of information could easily get lost or intimidated by the stretched winding offshoots of threads on Reddit. They might prefer a more direct moderated Q/A style or perhaps a more linear forum style that they can scroll. As long as they can get the help they need, that's what matters. Painting things as a competition can be confusing for those seeking help, as well as lead to negative repercussions for the respective sites.

Comment: ok so how shall I rephrase "Note that this Reddit sub [https://www.reddit.com/r/USCIS/] is way more informative than this Stack Exchange site." so that you don't think it makes it look a competition?

Comment: do you have any updates on this? Let me know how I should rephrase. Thanks.